# Cannot remotely connect to oracle express

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have installed Oracle Express in a **oracle-6.5-x64** virtual machine (let's called it *host*). The installation went fine, I am able to connect and run commands using SQLPlus from the host.

Now I'm trying to use SQLPlus from my Mac notebook (let's call it *client*) to access that remote database. I have installed the client packages and set the proper environment variables. I have tried connecting using EZConnect:

```
sqlplus system/<password>@<host-ip>[:1521]/XE
```

and also with TNS:

```
sqlplus system/<password>@XE
```

Both commands give me the following message:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

For the last option I have created a tnsnames.ora file in the client and exported a **TNS_ADMIN** variable pointing to the folder containing that file. The contents of tnsnames.ora are:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oraclehost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

I have tried using the host's IP instead of the hostname:

```
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.33.1)(PORT = 1521))
```

But that failed as well.

The **lsnrctl status** command on the host returns the following:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 09-JUL-2014 11:39:22

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Estabelecendo conexão com (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS do LISTENER
------------------------
Apelido                   LISTENER
Versão                    TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Data Inicial              09-JUL-2014 11:31:24
Funcionamento         0 dias 0 hr. 7 min. 58 seg
Nível de Análise     off
Segurança              ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Serviço Default           XE
Arq. Parâm. Listn.    /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Arq. Log Listener    /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/oraclehost/listener/alert/log.xml
Resumo de Atendimento...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oraclehost)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oraclehost)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Resumo de Serviços...
O serviço "PLSExtProc" tem 1 instância(s).
  Instância "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, tem 1 handler(s) para este serviço...
O serviço "XE" tem 1 instância(s).
  Instância "XE", status READY, tem 1 handler(s) para este serviço...
O serviço "XEXDB" tem 1 instância(s).
  Instância "XE", status READY, tem 1 handler(s) para este serviço...
O comando foi executado com êxito
```

As a last resource I have changed added **oraclehost** to the client's **/etc/hosts** file:

```
192.168.33.1    oraclehost
```

So I am able to successfully **ping** the host machine from the cliente by IP or hostname.

Answer (score 3):

More often than not, a firewall on the database vm is the culprit.
You can test this with

`telnet oraclehost 1521`

from your mac. This should give a quick response. If it does not give a quick response, like not response at all, a firewall is blocking the request. In that case allow traffic on port 1521, or disable the firewall.

Comment: Ok. I was finally able to stablish a connection. I'm using Vagrant to start up the VM hosting Oracle. So I just included the following configuration in the Vagrantfile: `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 1521, host: 1521 //   config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 1158, host: 1158`  I don't know what that did exactly, but I'm glad it worked :)